# Error while install MD Bootsrap 5 in my react js

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

[image]

When I want to install a plugin in react js using MD Bootstrap 5 then it gives me an error. I have done with installing **mdb-react-ui-kit** in my package.json file.

Comment: Please share code, error messages and stack traces always as text rather than screenshot. It will make it easier for others to work on your issue, hence chances are better that you get something helpful in reply. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `git` commands with `npm.` `git` is a source control software while npm is a package manager for node.

If you want to `clone` a project you can run:

```
git clone <repo_address>
```

If you want to `install` an npm package, you need to be inside the project folder that you want to install, make sure that there is a `package.json` file and run:

```
npm i mdb-react-ui-kit
```

Comment: I already install mdb-react-ui-kit using
npm i git+https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/react/mdb5/prd/mdb5-react-ui-kit-pro-essential#4.1.0

I want to install their plug *tree-view*